# Make copy of the screen to use in glasses. Android

Tags: java, android

I need to duplicate screen of my application to use it on the glasses hardware.
I have only one activity, so started with the simplest solution:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/copy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the repeating copy function:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getWidth(),
            root.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
root.draw(c);
BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(r, b);
copy.setBackground(d);
```

Works well, but not for the video or some other specific views inside root layout.

How to fix this, or some other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
Use SurfaceView as a target view

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/copy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

And use MediaProjection:

```
private MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager;
private MediaProjection mediaProjection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(
            android.content.Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    Intent permissionIntent = mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
    activity.startActivityForResult(permissionIntent, MEDIA_PROJECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (MEDIA_PROJECTION_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(
                    android.content.Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
            mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, intent);
            startRecording(mediaProjection);
        }
    }
}

public void startRecording(MediaProjection mediaProjection) {
    DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    Display defaultDisplay = null;
    if (dm != null) {
        defaultDisplay = dm.getDisplay(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    }
    if (defaultDisplay == null) {
        return;
    }

    DisplayMetrics metrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

    Surface inputSurface = copy.getHolder().getSurface();

    mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("Recording Display", screenWidth,
            screenHeight, screenDensity, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, inputSurface,
            null, null);
}
```

This completely resolve the task, all we have on the screen are duplicated.
But more elegant solutions of the task are welcome.